# How can a web application hide network traffic in DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

i am trying to reverse-engineer a trading application. The application displays stock price data which are updated in real time, yet I can't see any of the updates in Chrome devtools. I searched in:

- the Network tab (no fetch/xhr requests once the page is loaded)
- WebSocket tab (no WebSocket)
- Network tab of the service worker (same story)

Is there some other way that a webpage can use to get the data? Where else can I search for the requests?

Comment: You probably have missed its WebSocket request if you opened devtools after the page loaded. Open devtools and then reload the page to capture everything. Anyway you can inspect the network transport internals via `chrome://net-export` page.

Comment: Incredible, a custom stock app that isn't using Pine-script , then again, that industry is built on cash, so its surprising you don't see more of this.

Comment: @wOxxOm no I have not. I know WS don't show up if they are created before you open DevTools.. Not sure whether it could be the problem with the ServiceWorker, although I unregistered, terminated them and still couldn't see anything